# Windows Phone 7.1 emulator not working on Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-8.1

I tried to run the Windows Phone 7.1 emulator on Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. When I start the emulator, it shows the following error.

[image: Image one]

Followed by this error when I press "Run the program without getting help":

[image: Image two]

WHY WINDOWS PHONE 7.1 SDK, NOT WINDOWS PHONE 8:

The reason why I am setting this up as such is because I want to develop XNA games for Windows Phone 7 to 8. Hence the reason why I am still using the Windows Phone 7.1 developer kit. I have previously created and published XNA games (educational) in Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2010. I am using Visual Studio 2013 this time around because I would like to use the latest VS for all my programming needs.

Exact steps taken:

1. Install VS 2013 quite awhile ago
2. Update to Windows 8.1 yesterday
3. Downloaded Windows Phone 7.1 developer kit
4. Tried to run the emulator but it failed as described above!
5. TRIED TO INSTALL WINDOWS PHONE 7.1.1 UPDATE IN ATTEMPT TO FIX IT, THE INSTALLATION GAVE THE FOLLOWING ERROR "Fatal error during installation". The installation failed.
6. Searching of all possible solutions but so far I have been unable to find out how to install Windows Phone 7.1.1 update.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8.0 SDK include the ability to create apps for 7.1 and 8.0 so there should be no need to install the 7.1 SDK.

**HOWEVER**

Developing apps for 7.x is not supported in Visual Studio 2013.
If you must target 7.x devices you'll need to use VS2010 or VS2012.

If you want o build for Windows Phone 7.x you should use Visual Studio 2012. You can install this AND Visual Studio 2013 on the same machine. The only thing you may not end up being able to do is having a single solution with all projects in that you can use in both versions of VS.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed explanation! I have installed Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and VS2012.


When I start an XNA Game Studio 4.0 project, it asks me to target either 7.0 or 7.1. I chose 7.1 and I ran the emulator. Is the right way to go?


When I start the emulator, it flashes the cornflowerblue screen and the home screen for Windows Phone. Do you have any clue as to what is causing this problem?

Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: I have fixed the flashing issue by using Intel integrated graphics instead of the high-performance Nvdia GPU! Found this fix somewhere on the Internet while I was looking to fix my previous issue. Lost the link!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570,
The Windows Phone SDK 7.1 is only compatible with Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

According to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233,
The Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update is also only compatible with Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

Try installing the Windows Phone SDK update for Windows Phone 7.8, which is compatible with Windows 8 and Windows 8 Pro:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474