# Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Just updated my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to update 3. The Windows Dev Center states:

> The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are installed with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 2 or later and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later.

but I can't find a template to start a Windows phone project.

[image: http://pasteboard.co/2rC8WtYk.png]

Comment: Did you select Windows Phone from the list of options during installation? They are not selected by default I think.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319443/no-template-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-visual-studio-express-2013-with-update-2-rc) might help you to resolve the issue

Comment: There was no list of options when installing update 3

Comment: I do not have a Store Apps template option and I used the ISO to install the update so neither answer seems to apply.

Comment: Might be worth reinstall VS2013, because like Abhishek mentioned you should be able to select the SDK during the installation

Comment: [This](http://pasteboard.co/2rDRegCc.png) is what I see when selecting a modify setup from the original ISO which doesn't contain any updates. Also the Windows Phone SDK is installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone'

Comment: Pretty sure that you NEED to have Windows 8 installed with VS2013, are you using Windows 7 maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Have found answers related to Windows Phone SDK 7 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23987711/3897585